# How to convert rosgraph output to graphical representation?

Tags: ros, rosgraph

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there some way to convert the output of [rosgraph](http://wiki.ros.org/rosgraph) to a graphical representation similar to the one of [rqt_graph](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_graph)? (I am interested in a way to do that in ros1 indigo.)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287962/how-to-convert-rosgraph-output-to-graphical-representation?/) by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 468 on 2018-04-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It depends a bit on what you mean exactly by *rosgraph output*, but if you're after the kind of diagram that `rqt_graph` shows, then that would be basically a rendering of a `dot` graph.

I'm not aware of any stand-alone tools that will render those for you, but a good starting point would be the code in `rqt_graph`, specifically [RosGraph._update_rosgraph()](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_graph/blob/90117a0b04c99d1baf4589dc97751fa3487883a4/src/rqt_graph/ros_graph.py#L208-L226), which calls [RosGraph._generate_dotcode()](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_graph/blob/90117a0b04c99d1baf4589dc97751fa3487883a4/src/rqt_graph/ros_graph.py#L233-L260) which uses [RosGraphDotcodeGenerator.generate_dotgraph(..)](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_graph/blob/90117a0b04c99d1baf4589dc97751fa3487883a4/src/rqt_graph/dotcode.py#L423-L439) to generate the actual `dot` markup.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2018-04-09**:
Exactly, I was thinking about a diagram. Thanks for the hint! In case one would like to add a "converter" functionality to e.g. rosgraph where would the most suitable place to add it there?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-09**:
`rosgraph` itself doesn't have any dependencies right now other than `rospkg`. It's probably best to keep it that way.

Seeing as `rqt_graph` already contains the infrastructure, perhaps adding a stand-alone command line script there would be nice.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-09**:
Alternatively, I could imagine that refactoring `rqt_graph` to make the `RosGraphDotcodeGenerator` into a stand-alone library might also make sense. `rqt_graph` could then use that, as well as a new tool that does what you are after.

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2018-04-09**:
Using one of your suggested approaches could it be made compatible with [rqt_graph - "Topic statistics"](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_graph)?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-09**:
I'm unsure as to what you're asking: `rqt_graph` already renders the topic statistics, if they are available. I haven't checked, but I would imagine that the same code that generates the `dot` graph adds the statistics.

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2018-04-09**:
I have statistics enabled with `rosparam set enable_statistics true`. I cannot run `rgt_graph` for displaying a diagram on the system I am working on. I am not seeing any `/statistics` topic. seems like `rqt_graph` is not installed on there...

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-09**:
Statistics gathering is independent of `rqt_graph`. If you're not seeing the topic then that would be a different issue. It is a prerequisite for `rqt_graph` (or some other tool) to visualise them though (obviously).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-09**:
Did you see the note on [wiki/Topics - Topic statistics](http://wiki.ros.org/Topics#Topic_statistics):

> this parameter has to be set before you start your nodes

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2018-04-09**:
Ah, right. I miss-interpreted the both wiki sites [rqt_graph](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_graph) and [Topics - Topic statistics](http://wiki.ros.org/Topics#Topic_statistics) (I thought the gathering relates to rqt_graph).

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2018-04-09**:
...and I missed that the parameter has to be set before starting the nodes. Thanks!

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2018-04-09**:
(Only for reference: Statistics info is always included in message: http://docs.ros.org/api/rosgraph_msgs/html/msg/TopicStatistics.html)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-16**:
I just came across [ludusrusso/rosgraph_web_visualizer](https://github.com/ludusrusso/rosgraph_web_visualizer). It's not a command line tool, but might be interesting none-the-less.